# R - multicore approach to extract raster values using spatial points

Tags: raster, r, point, extract, parallel-processing

It might look like this question is duplicated, but I'm asking about data extraction by **points**, rather than by **polygons**, and I couldn't find hints about point extraction. Therefore, please bare with me.

I am working with a massive amount of climate files whose values need to be extracted and converted to data frames in order to serve as a database for a Shiny application.

Specifically, I need to extract **daily** temperature values from a raster stack for 655 locations (points) and store those values in a data frame. Given the amount of data, I estimate the final data frame to be around **30 GB** in size.

Since it is such a big amount of data, I am looking to use a multicore (parallel) approach that benefits from a quad core (8 threads) system. I also consider to process these data on an Amazon EC2 instance, so I need to speed up the code as much as I can in order to prevent wasting time (i.e. money).

I know that the `raster` package provides the multicore function `beginCluster` that might help me, but according to the documentation it only works when extracting data using *polygons*, not *points*.

Please take a look at the code that reproduces my procedure using a simplified version of my raster stack:

```
library(raster)

# Create date sequence
idx <- seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2099/12/31"), by = "day")

# Create raster stack and assign dates
# WARNING: raster stack will be ~ 400 MB in size
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5)
s <- stack(lapply(1:length(idx), function(x) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))))
s <- setZ(s, idx)

# Create random spatial points
pts <- SpatialPoints(cbind(x=runif(655, -180, 180),
                           y=runif(655, -90, 90)),
                     proj4string=CRS(projection(s)))

# Extract values to a data frame
e.df <- extract(s, pts, df=TRUE)

# Fix resulting data frame
DF <- data.frame(t(e.df[-1])); row.names(DF)=NULL
DF <- cbind(getZ(s), DF)
names(DF)[1] <- "Date";
names(DF)[2:length(names(DF))] <- paste0('Point ', 1:length(pts))
```

In the code above, clearly the slowest part of the process is the data extraction itself.

Is there any way to improve the speed of this data extraction procedure?

Any way to implement it under a multicore function?

Comment: I don't see where your 30Gb comes from. 89 years x 365 days x 655 stations is 21 million. You need to be handling about 1000 bytes for each of those units to get 30Gb, where one temperature measurement is 8 bytes. 160-250Mb maybe, which is easily stored in RAM.

Comment: This is "trivially parallel" over layers in your raster stack and over points in your spatial points. Use functions from the `parallel` package.

Comment: @Spacedman my actual raster stack is 100x95 at 0.5 deg resolution with 54750 "layers" (i.e. time slices). Also, I have 32 files like that that I need to extract data from (different climate scenarios and models). I just thought it was too big of an object for users to reproduce here.

Comment: @Spacedman I would also appreciate any more detailed suggestion regarding the `parallel` package. Not very familiar with multicore processing here...

Comment: Suggest you find some R parallel tutorials, things like this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf might get you started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using an approach based on the `snowfall` package. It is quite simple, works really good and the point extraction function is as fast as the number of cores that you can use. The approach I used was inspired by [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/davis-rug/iy_cMerPoHk), and here is my reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
library(snowfall)

# Create date sequence
idx <- seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2099/12/31"), by = "day")

# Create raster stack and assign dates
# WARNING: raster stack will be ~ 400 MB in size
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5)
s <- stack(lapply(1:length(idx), function(x) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))))
s <- setZ(s, idx)

# Create random spatial points
pts <- SpatialPoints(cbind(x=runif(655, -180, 180),
                           y=runif(655, -90, 90)),
                     proj4string=CRS(projection(s)))

# Extract values to a data frame - multicore approach
# First, convert raster stack to list of single raster layers
s.list <- unstack(s)
names(s.list) <- names(s)

# Now, create a R cluster using all the machine cores minus one
sfInit(parallel=TRUE, cpus=parallel:::detectCores()-1)

# Load the required packages inside the cluster
sfLibrary(raster)
sfLibrary(sp)

# Run parallelized 'extract' function and stop cluster
e.df <- sfSapply(s.list, extract, y=pts)
sfStop()

# Fix resulting data frame
DF <- data.frame(t(e.df)); row.names(DF)=NULL
DF <- cbind(getZ(s), DF)
names(DF)[1] <- "Date";
names(DF)[2:length(names(DF))] <- paste0('Point ', 1:length(pts))

# Check resulting data frame
head(DF)
```

I hope it can serve as a future reference for people interested in doing the same.