# Parallelize Extracting Large Raster Values (one band) to Points

Tags: raster, r, parallel-processing

I have sf data with single point geometries (`points`) and a 23,000 x 18,000 elevation RasterLayer with a single band, loaded from a geotiff (`elev`). They have the same CRS. I want to extract the elevation values to the points.

When I try running `extract(elev, points)`, since my raster is very large I get:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.1 Gb

I followed advice here [R - multicore approach to extract raster values using spatial points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253618/r-multicore-approach-to-extract-raster-values-using-spatial-points#254516) and tried to parallelize, but I only have a single raster, so chances are the work won't get divided. Still I try the following:

```
library(snowfall)
sfInit(parallel=TRUE, cpus=parallel:::detectCores()-1)
sfLibrary(raster)
sfLibrary(sp)

# Run parallelized 'extract' function and stop cluster
e.df <- sfSapply(elev, raster::extract, y=points)
sfStop()
```

I get the same result:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.1 Gb

All the examples I've found so far, such as the above, store multiple rasters in a list. **How do I parallelize extraction from a single raster like this?** Or is there a way to make use of sparse matrices and memory management as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)?

[image: points covering extent of elev raster]

I'm on Windows 10 running RStudio 1.1.419 (64 bit). 8GB RAM. Intel Core i5-6200U CPU @ 2.3GHz 2.4GHz

Comment: There is something not tracking here. I have extract ~1M points from a 2GB single-band raster and did not even touch the top of memory on my laptop. Most raster functions operate out of memory so do not read in a raster that large. The memory consumption should be around the raster block read in and the resulting vector associated with extract. For polygons I could easily see memory issues but just not with points. There is seemingly something else going on here. I would recommend trying the velox package to see if you get a memory error.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your image to tiles like `100*100` tiles, then loop tiles to extract points. Or you can try database solution with building spatial index. When you load your image to spatial database, it also can tile your image. `PostGIS` is open source, in `PostGIS` just a SQL query can do this job, the function is [ST_Value](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html).

[EDIT]You can loop records(here are tiles) using `PL/pgSQL` like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION work_on_tiles() AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    FOR tile IN
        SELECT rast FROM public.elev WHERE rid > 0
    LOOP
        -- can do some processing here
        var = ST_Value(rast)
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM work_on_tiles();
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using a version of the raster I loaded in postgis, but I'm not sure how it works. `raster2pgsql -I -C -s 26985 -t 182x226 "~/elev.tif" public.elev | psql -d postgres`. After reading the resulting `elev` table from my psql connection, I don't know how to loop over tiles, so I'm probably only getting one

Comment: @Wassadamo you have almost worked it out. You can use PLpgsql language to loop table records(here is tiles) to apply ST_Value.